# External Stylessheets with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get all the external stylesheets in puppeteer Js and i am not getting only one. 
here is my code:

```
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('response', async response => { // don't await anything on this line
        if(response.request().resourceType() === 'stylesheet') {
            resolve(response.text()); // await and resolve here
        }
    });

    await page.goto(url);
    await browser.close();
    // don't resolve here
} catch (e) {
    return reject(e);
}
```

The problem here is when i have more than 1 external stylesheets i am not able ot get them. How would i achieve that

> NOTE: I am using resolve because i need the stylesheets for further
>   processing. and ineed them returned.

Comment: I think the problem is `response` event happen multiple times but you `resolve` it at the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can add all stylesheets (or their Promises) to an array and then resolve it, after the page is loaded and the Promises are resolved.

**Code**

```js
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const stylesheetPromises = [];

    page.on('response', async response => {
        if(response.request().resourceType() === 'stylesheet') {
            stylesheet.push(response.text());
        }
    });

    await page.goto(url);
    await browser.close();
    const stylesheets = await Promise.all(stylesheetPromises);
    resolve(stylesheets);
} catch (e) {
    return reject(e);
}
```

The Promise (which I assume this code is inside) is then resolved with an array of strings containing all the stylesheets. This is done by adding all the Promises of `response.text()` to an array, which we finally `await` via `Promise.all`. After that the results are returned.